# Broken image links causing high load on server. Symfony2/Apache

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu-14.04

I have a website built in Symfony 2.8 running on Apache on Ubuntu Server. I had some broken image links on the website, and whenever somebody went to the offending page, it would peg out both the processor and memory, and the browser would continue to try and fetch the missing assets for 60 seconds plus.

I've fixed the missing images, but is there something I can do on the server end to quit searching for missing assets when they're clearly not there?

The way it stands now it would be very easy for an attacker to simply demand content from my website that isn't there, and bring my server to it's knees.

**--Edit--**

What I'm wondering if there is a way to stop my server from taking a resource hit if somebody tries to access a path/file that's non-existent directly. i.e. if they went directly to example.com/images/non-existent.jpg. Currently on my server my CPU will spike to 100% on one core and RAM usage will slowly climb until the request times out somewhere around 1 min. Just a few more requests like that would use all of my resources.

**--Edit 2--**

I have discovered since I posted this, that this isn't just limited to images. Any path that should return a 404 error is behaving the same. ie example.com/this/is/not/a/real/path will just hang, and finally time out.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the file exsists before including it in your HTML

```
if(file_exists('img.jpg')){
    // your code for inserting the image into the HTML
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question, but I know how to check if a file is there in php. What I'm wondering if there is a way to stop my server from taking a resource hit if somebody tries to access a path/file that's non-existent directly.
i.e. if they went directly to example.com/images/non-existent.jpg. Currently on my server my CPU will spike to 100% on one core and RAM usage will slowly climb until the request times out somewhere around 1 min.

Comment: @chrislebaron after reading your update, if someone accesses a file that doesn't exists the server should simply throw a 404 error

Comment: I would have to agree that is the behavior I want to happen, but for some reason it's not. Perhaps I have Symfony configured wrong somehow. I've tried going to a non-existent resource on several browsers and it just hangs for about a minute and then gives and empty response error.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Symfony because you said this also happens when you directly access the file, the Symfony stack isn't hit in this case. It has to be an apache config somewhere

Comment: that makes sense. I'll have to look into the apache config and see if I find anything awry. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using some sort of image caching (E.g. liipimagine or similar?) There must be some sort of processing going on there for the CPU to spike like that on a simple image 404.

Comment: I am caching PHP, not images though. Off the top of my head I don't remember exactly what I'm using for php caching. I have noticed this doesn't only apply to images, but any page or image that doesn't exist on my server doesn't return a 404 error. ie both example.com/images/foo.jpg and example.com/non/existent/path.

Comment: You should find out if this is an Apache issue or a Symfony / PHP issue.  in your app.php file, on the first line, try to return a dummy response. then go to your 404 page. See how fast the dummy page loads. If it is fast then you have a Symfony / PHP issue. If it loads as slow as before then you have an Apache issue